# How can I unnest a long column(map) to multiple columns with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, unnest

I have a dataframe like this:

dataframe name: df_test

| ID | Data |
| --- | --- |
| test-001 | `{"B":{"1":{"_seconds":1663207410,"_nanoseconds":466000000}},"C":{"1":{"_seconds":1663207409,"_nanoseconds":978000000}},"D":{"1":{"_seconds":1663207417,"_nanoseconds":231000000}}}` |
| test-002 | `{"B":{"1":{"_seconds":1663202431,"_nanoseconds":134000000}},"C":{"1":{"_seconds":1663208245,"_nanoseconds":412000000}},"D":{"1":{"_seconds":1663203482,"_nanoseconds":682000000}}}` |

I want it to be unnested like this:

| ID | B_1_seconds | B_1_nanoseconds | C_1_seconds | C_1_nanoseconds | D__seconds | D__nanoseconds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test-001 | 1663207410 | 466000000 | 1663207409 | 978000000 | 1663207417 | 231000000 |
| test-002 | 1663202431 | 134000000 | 1663208245 | 412000000 | 1663203482 | 682000000 |

I tryed df_test.explode but it doesn't work for this

I used Dataiku to unnest the data and it worked perfectly, now I want to unnest the data within my python notebook, what should I do?

Edit:
I tried
`df_list=df_test["data"].tolist()`
then

```
pd.json_normalize.(df_list)
```

it returned an empty dataframe with only index but no value in it.

Comment: to unpack nested dictionaries use pd.json_normalize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `pd.json_normalize` returns an empty dataframe I'd guess that `df["Data"]` contains strings? If that's the case you could try

```py
import json

df_data = pd.json_normalize(json.loads("[" +  ",".join(df["Data"]) + "]"), sep="_")
res = pd.concat([df[["ID"]], df_data], axis=1).rename(lambda c: c.replace("__", "_"), axis=1)
```

or

```py
df_data = pd.json_normalize(df["Data"].map(eval), sep="_")
res = pd.concat([df[["ID"]], df_data], axis=1).rename(lambda c: c.replace("__", "_"), axis=1)
```

Result for both alternatives is:

```
         ID  B_1_seconds  B_1_nanoseconds  C_1_seconds  C_1_nanoseconds  \
0  test-001   1663207410        466000000   1663207409        978000000   
1  test-002   1663202431        134000000   1663208245        412000000   

   D_1_seconds  D_1_nanoseconds  
0   1663207417        231000000  
1   1663203482        682000000
```